# solr like search using custom type

Tags: solr

I am using Solr. I need to search those keyword which we get by using like
for example i want to search for x1 carbon ,
in my sql i search i get the correct result

```
select * from table where name like "%x1 carbon%"
```

In solr i get the correct result but i donot get entries with say for example,but i get the below entries in mysql using like "%text%"

*x1 carbon
x1 carbon*
*x1 carbon*
.................

My schema is below

```
<fieldType name="text_general_k" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

What should i do to get the above vaules also like

someword_x1 carbon

and

someword_x1 carbon_ ?

with this schema im not getting

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

    <fieldType name="text_general_k" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" /> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Im attaching the sceenshot of query analyuzer

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use partial math?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below custom field type for you field.

```
<fieldType name="likeField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" /> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

With the configuration below the string value **Nigerian** gets broken down to the following terms

```
Nigerian => "ni", "nig", "nige", "niger", "nigeri", "nigeria", "nigeria", "nigerian"
```

Comment: No ,im sorry not getting proper results ,basically i require it to access _x1 carbon,x1 carbon _ and _x1 carbon_ also ..............

Comment: Did you tried the above fieldType for you field and re-ndexed the data? Did you tried the same on solr analysis page? Can you tell me what all worked and what all search did not work?

Comment: Thanks for the help,Yes ..I tried using the above setting ,the problem is it is not able to get the search results like 
_x1 carbon
x1 carbon_
_x1 carbon_
All other results are fine ,im getting results like "x1 carbon".
I used field8:("x1 carbon") in the solr query

Comment: Anybody has come across this issue ?

Comment: Can you show the indexed created on the solr analysis page and which all gets matched...? because as the mingramSize is 2 , it should have the index x1 and should match your criteria.

Comment: @markrammmy : the UI shows that the text "x1 carbon" is matching ...now whats the issue then?

Comment: The problem is its not matching _x1 carbon and x1 carbon _

Comment: The problem is with underscorex1 carbon

Comment: Are you indexing the _x1 or carbon_?...I mean are you passing any text similar for indexing...? Pass same text for indexing and check the same text in the query...? if the tokens are not created for the text  _x1 then it would be the issue